# Изменение значений .json файла

Tags: android, kotlin

Я попробовал различные библиотеки для работы с JSON файлами, какую можете посоветовать самую простую, `Klaxon` я уже пробовал, но там вроде как недоступны изменения значений в файле, у них на `github.com` на эту тему было написано, как раз. Хотелось бы в ответе увидеть пример использования, у меня есть такой файл

```
{   "list": {     "item_1":0,     "item_2":0,     "item_3": 0,     "item_4": 0   } }
```

и как я могу поменять значение у `item_1` на `1` например?

Comment: JSON файл не меняется, он читается и десериализируется в структуру, структуру меняйте как хотите, потом сериализуете обратно в JSON и файл переписываете. Для этого и без библиотек можно обойтись, все есть в Android SDK.

Comment: читаете Json в нужный вам объект класса. меняете значение в этом объекте. преобразовываете объект в json. делается абсолютно любой библиотекой.

Comment: @Wlad  
`data class YourModel(
var list: Map<Any,Any>
        )
var yourModel = Gson().fromJson(File(filesDir, "complite").readText(), YourModel::class.java)
yourModel.list["item_1"] = 1
var jsonString = Gson().toJson(yourModel)`
Вот я пробую, но у меня на строчке где я присваиваю элементу значение, ошибка `No set method providing array access`
Я делаю, что-то не так, или путь верный и нужно просто разобраться в документации?

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказали в комментариях можно:

### читаете Json в нужный вам объект класса. меняете значение в этом объекте. преобразовываете объект в json. делается абсолютно любой библиотекой

Решил взять самую простую, на мой взгляд библиотеку `Gson`

```
 data class YourModel(
        var list_of_comp: MutableMap<Any,Any>,
    )
    var yourModel = Gson().fromJson(File(filesDir, "complite").readText(), YourModel::class.java)
    yourModel.list_of_comp["item_1"] = 1

    var jsonString = Gson().toJson(yourModel)
```

И вуаля, значение поменялось, и `jsonString` можно записать куда угодно, так как это измененный файл